# How to remove colon within array string in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

y foreach loop like

```
foreach($set as $messaccesstoken => $mertid){
```

the loop gives me array like

```
Array ([1] => m_mid.1423282844838:1d2ec85ca015107784[2] => m_mid.1390680182411:d4ca154850b82d1931 [3] => m_id.199186660280356 )
```

the third element is different so foreach loop stop i just want to skip third element and jump to another element to continue my loop

I have many array element like that except when it find `m_id.199186660280356` the foreach loop stop execution because all array string are like `m_mid.1423282844838:1d2ec85ca015107784` but when it find structure like `m_id.199186660280356` loop stop i just want to use if loop when it find colon in array element the loop continue so how i can done in php. can someone help me? thanks

Comment: Can you post your foreach logic?

Comment: @Jesse i have a foreach loop where many ids are comming and i just fetch one at a time and when it find array element like i post it stop execution and return empty array.

Comment: From your question it is difficult to understand what you want to archive. If you want to find whether the strings in your array contain a colon or not you could use `if (strpos($str,':') !== false) {    echo 'true';   }`  You can easily skip an iteration of the loop by using `continue`

Comment: @AmitSingh post your code what have you tried

Comment: Please post your expected output

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues i post my problem and code

Comment: Amit to be honest there isn't much code in your post... You've just added the start of the foreach loop and nothing else.
Also include the expected output as suggested by @Uchiha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we are unable to see your foreach loop in your brain since it is not in the post, but you can find a [string](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) in a [string](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) using [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) (among other ways). Since I have no code to try and modify, you can see this logic on how strpos works and inherit it in your code (that we can't see because it's a secret, shhh) ::

```
foreach( $array as &$value ) {
    if( strpos($value, ':' ) ) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this via regular expression.

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
    if( preg_match('/^([a-zA-z0-9]+):([a-zA-z0-9]+)$/',$value) ) {
        // Do your code.
    } else 
       continue;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely. There is more than one way to do almost everything and this is totally a viable option. Keep in mind, readability, however when others review code you may have written. Your code should be easily accessible by the next programmer, preferably, at a glance.